# US-rated glue gun on European grid

Tags: mains

Some time ago, I received a care package from the US, which included a glue gun (specifically, this one: https://surebonder.com/collections/plus-series/products/dt-270f-plus-series-40-watt-full-size-dual-temperature-hot-glue-gun) which is rated to use US mains power. Living, as I do, in Norway, 115 VAC is not readily available as the default in these parts is 230 VAC.

What I am wondering is, if I replace the plug with a Norwegian one, would it be safe to use on a Norwegian outlet?

Comment: No. (just to fill the space).

Comment: No! No! No! No! (No need to fill the space)

Comment: So I'm guessing that's a no-no? Good things, I assumed as much but wanted to check.

Comment: There is a good chance it will fail catastrophically. It would be wise not to use it. Or, as so many people seem to do it nowadays, find a fireproof place, plug it in, film the explosion (in slow mo), upload it on youtube, profit (or not).

Comment: *Best* case scenario: you'll trip the circuit breaker.

Comment: All my electronics training and instinct says **no**, but at my workplace we have a glue gun labeled 110V and we use it on 240V without issues. Also some glue guns are rated for 110-240V but have no switch or other electronics to change voltages. They simply rely on the heating element's large positive temperature coefficient. https://lorimer.id.au/glue.html

Answer (score 1):

*if I replace the plug with a Norwegian one, would it be safe to use on a Norwegian outlet?*

No, because the voltage is **double** to what the glue gun is designed for so the heating element will heat up not with two times but **four** times more power than normal (the doubled voltage also causes the current to double). If it does not break immediately then the glue will probably get too hot and who knows what can happen as a result of that.

**Never** use a device which is not rated for use at 230 VAC at that voltage.

Also, a new Glue gun will cost a whopping 5 Euros perhaps. So why not just get a new one suitable for Norway?

If you have more devices which need 115 VAC you could get a transformer for 230 VAC to 115 VAC but that might be expensive, especially for high power.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can probably use one of those cheap travel converters which internally are just a diode to half-wave rectify the mains, since the hot glue gun is only a heater.

[image]

Comment: A glue gun is cheaper than these :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. the ones that are nothing but a half wave rectifier are pretty cheap